# Packaging AIR apps with ADT gives wrong namespace error on Windows, works on Mac

Tags: apache-flex, air, adt

I'm packiging AIR app both on Mac and on Windows. On Mac everything goes well, but on Windows I get an error.

Myapp-app.xml: error 102: Invalid namespace http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.5

I have latest SDK's installed on both machines, although Flash Builder is newer on Mac. Does the Flash Builder version even matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash Builder version will affect your build if you don't specify manually the location of the Air 2.5 SDK.  By default, I believe FB 4.5 always points to 2.5, but 4.0 points to 2.0.

Comment: I'm doing it from command line, does FB still have the effect? How do I point to the correct SDK within the command line parameter, do you have an example? I find the ADT command line params pretty confusing.

Comment: Oh, you're probably not using ADT from the Air 2.5 SDK.  Just get the Air 2.5 (or 2.6) sdk from Adobe and run adt from the bin folder.

Comment: True, I had correct path on Mac but missed framework and framework\air paths on Windows.